# Symbol's function definition is void: use-package

Tags: init-file, themes, use-package

I am unable to get the [darcula theme](https://gitlab.com/fommil/emacs-darcula-theme) working.

I have a tried moving `(package-initialize)` and `(require 'package)` but I am unable to get it working.

[image]

Here is my init.el file.

```
;; Added by Package.el.  This must come before configurations of
;; installed packages.  Don't delete this line.  If you don't want it,
;; just comment it out by adding a semicolon to the start of the line.
;; You may delete these explanatory comments.
(package-initialize)

;; hide toolbar
;;
;; https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ToolBar#toc1
(tool-bar-mode -1)

;; hide scrollbar
;;
;; https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ScrollBar
(scroll-bar-mode -1)

;; hide menubar
;;
;; https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MenuBar
(menu-bar-mode -1)

;; hide splash screen
;;
;; http://stackoverflow.com/a/744681/3034693
(setq inhibit-startup-screen t)

;; hide scratch message
;;
;; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498258/how-do-i-change-the-scratch-message-in-emacs
(setq initial-scratch-message nil)

;; repository
;;
;; 
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))

(custom-set-variables
 ;; maximize frame on start
 ;;
 ;; https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FullScreen#toc2
 '(default-frame-alist (quote ((fullscreen . maximized))))
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(package-selected-packages (quote (darcula-theme))))

(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )

;; Darcula - Emacs theme inspired by IntelliJ's Darcula.
;;
;; https://gitlab.com/fommil/emacs-darcula-theme
(use-package darcula-theme
  :ensure t
  :config
  ;; your preferred main font face here
  (set-frame-font "Source Code Pro-10"))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The emacs-darcula-theme README suggests installing via `use-package`, but this requires installing the `use-package` first.  Since you've already installed the darcula-theme package, you can just do a plain `require` instead of `use-package`:

```el
(require 'darcula-theme)
(set-frame-font "Inconsolata-14")
```